# How to insert Data to Database using JSP

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, insert

I know this Question is already asked,unfortunately the answers cant help me to solve my Problem.

I have a working Mysql Database "Test", where i save my Data(only Strings).
The following Code shows my `<div>`-Container ,where i get my Data from.

```
<form action="index.jsp" method="POST">
  <div .....>

   <input type"text" name="termin" />
   <input type="submit" value="submit" />

  </div>
</form>
```

AS JSP Code i use :

```
<%
int result = 0;
String name = request.getParameter("termin");


Termin t1 = new Termin();
result = t1.setTermin(name);
%>
```

The first time i click on Submit-Button, it adds NULL to my Database.If i click another time, it doesnt change the Database.

Someone has an idea what is going on?
EDIT: My Fault it should be name instead of data

```
public class Termin {
String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
String username="root";
String pw = "root";

Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
ResultSet res = null;

public Termin() {
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,username,pw);


    }catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public int setTermin(String tname) {
    int result = 0;
    try {
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(
                "INSERT INTO ver(TName) VALUES(?);");
        stmt.setString(1,tname);
        result = stmt.executeUpdate();
        stmt.clearParameters();
    }catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```

}

Comment: First of all don't use java code (scriptlet) in jsp file, secondly Post the code of your *Termin* class and where are you using `name`

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the fact that you're not doing anything with `name` ? Without seeing the other parts of the implementation one could only guess...

Comment: If you can show code in Termin class will be good. Other thing where are you using name in query .

Comment: Where should i put my Java-Code in the JSP-FIle instad?

Comment: I figured out what the Problem is,when i load the Page my Input Field is Empty, thats why my Databse has this empty String in it.But still, if i click a second time on submit,it doesnt work...

Answer (score 0):

There is no condition in order to check if parameter named `termin` is empty or not. So when you load jsp page, java codes are executed and because the parameter has no value , `null` is saved in database.

Comment: int result = 0;
 String name = new String();

 if(request.getParameter("termin") != null) {
  name = request.getParameter("termin");
  
 }

 Termin t1 = new Termin();
 result = t1.setTermin(name);               
Now it is saving an Empty String, and it is still not working if i click a second Time on the Submit Button :)